# Un cancel? A word or phrase to say I'd like to cancel my cancellation

Tags: british-english, synonyms, doubled-words

Say I have cancelled an appointment, but I then decide that I would like to go after all, so I cancel the cancellation... Do I uncancel the appointment? Seems a bit clumsy even if it's a valid expression.

Comment: Of course, you then can  recancel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I need to do this I call to **rebook** the appointment. That is the same as calling to **reinstate** the booking.

Alternatively, you can **revoke**, **reverse**, or **undo** the cancellation.

Comment: Thanks, I do like reinstate cancelled appointment, has a clarity about it

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I like **rebook**. 
You could also say **undo** or **reschedule**, but the latter could also be inferred as you are scheduling for a different time.